# [ASP .NET]Jquery UI Modal Dialog not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a trouble with dialog jquery, this is my code :

```
$(function () {
                showModalUserNickName();
            });

            function showModalUserNickName() {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            alert("it's OK");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

what wrong with my code, I hope you can help my problem

thank's before

Comment: getting any console errors???

Comment: I don't have console error

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code to jsFiddle and it works good.
Here is a snippet: [working code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/5betuL1w/2/)

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog title">This is dialog</div>
```

Possibly you have problem in some other place.

- Check whether your div with id "dialog" exists
- Check whether your JQuery and JQuery-ui versions are compatible. Not working code snippet: [not working snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/5betuL1w/), the difference only in JQuery and JQuery-UI versions